# What does the length of BP approach?

Tags: geometry, bisection

Given isosceles triangle $ABC$ below with $\angle{B}=\angle{C}$ and $BC=1$. Let point $P$ be the intersection of the line bisecting $\angle{B}$ and $AC$. Determine the length of $BP$ as the length of $AM$ approaches 0.
[image]

My answer was $\frac34$ but the answer was $\frac23$.

My attempt:
Since the problem didn't really state what was $AM$, I set $AM$ to be the non-trivial perpendicular bisector. Because we are finding the median, I noted that this triangle is also half of a parallelogram where $AC$ is one diagonal and $BF$ is the other where point $F$ is on the parallelogram. Using the law of cosines, you can find that
$$(AC)^2+(BF)^2=2(AB)^2+2(BC)^2$$
Since $BF$ is twice the length of $BP$, divide $BF$ by 2 to get $BP$.

If we let $AM$ by y, then by the Pythagorean theorem we can say that $AC = \sqrt{y^2+\frac14}$

We can then plug into the previous formula to get
$$(2BP)^2+(y^2+\frac14)=2(1)+2(y^2+1)$$
So
$$BP=\frac{\sqrt{y^2+\frac94}}{2}$$

As $AM$ approaches $0$, then $y$ approaches $0$ as well.
This means that $BP=\frac{\sqrt{\frac94}}{2}=\frac34$

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your line of reasoning is flawed.

> Because we are finding the median, I noted that this triangle is also half of a parallelogram where $AC$ is one diagonal and $BF$ is the other where point $F$ is on the parallelogram.
>   
>  ...
>   
> Since $BF$ is twice the length of $BP$, divide $BF$ by 2 to get $BP$.

$BP$ is not a median, it is a bisector. And in a generic parallelogram, the diagonals are *not* bisectors of its angles. The intersection of $BF$ and $AC$ would be the midpoint $Q$ of $AC$, not $P$. So, the length of $BF$ is *not* twice the length of $BP$ - it is twice the length of $BQ$ instead. What you proved is that the length of $BQ$ tends to $\frac{3}{4}$ as $A \to M$, which is correct but not what the problem asked.

Back to the question now, consider that $\frac{PA}{PC} = \frac{BA}{BC}$ by the [bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem).
When $A \to M$ we have $PA \to PM$ and $BA \to BM$ so $\frac{PA}{PC} \to \frac{PM}{PC} = \frac{BM}{BC} = \frac{1}{2}$.
 Thus at the limit $\frac{PM}{MC} = \frac{1}{3}$ so $PB = BM + MP = \frac{BC}{2} + \frac{MC}{3} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$ .

Comment: How could you assert that as $A$ approaches $M$ that $\frac{PM}{PC}→\frac{BM}{BC}$?

Comment: I would appreciate if you help explained why the problem states "line bisecting $∠B$ AND $AC$.

Comment: @IanLimarta When $A \to M$ it follows that $PA \to PM$ and $BA \to BM$.

Comment: @IanLimarta `Let point P be the intersection of the line bisecting B and AC` The line bisects $\angle B$, and  intersects $AC$ at $P$. It does *not* bisect $AC$.

Answer (score 0):

$PH$ is perpendicular to $BC$, $H$ on $BC$

$$\frac{\text{HM}}{\text{HC}}=\frac{\text{PA}}{\text{PC}}=\frac{b}{1}$$

$$\text{HM}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}b}{b+1}$$

$$\text{BH}=\frac{2b+1}{2(b+1)}$$

$b\rightarrow 1/2$ gives $\text{BH}\rightarrow \frac{2}{3} $and therefore $\text{BP}\rightarrow \frac{2}{3}$ since $\text{PH} \rightarrow 0$